# Activate sub on change of specific cell

Tags: cell, onchange

I am an inexperienced VBA programmer. I have a large model with multiple sub routines in modules. I have a spreadsheet with a drop down menu to select which depreciation type to use for fixed assets. the sub routine accesses this cell in the depreciation sub routine to know which type of formula to apply.

I want the subroutine to execute when a change is made to the drop down. I have tried a couple of methods. The first kicked off the subroutine but because the Call sub checks on the target cell the whole thing gets into a loop and Excel crashes.

To fix this I tried making another cell equal to the drop down target cell so that the referenced cell in the change sub routine was not the one accessed in the depreciation sub routine. I tried a couple of suggestions from you tube but the depreciation sub routine does not run in response to the change in the "dummy" target cell.

Any Ideas as to how to male this work?

Brian

Tried this last where $E$2 is the dummy target cell linked to the result of the drop down.

Public CurVal As String

Private Sub worksheet_activate()
CurVal = Range("$E$2")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
CurVal = Range("$E$2")
End Sub

Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$2" And Target <> CurVal Then
Call NLDep
End If
End Sub